# Can I save space in my Mongodb indexes by converting ASCII strings to bytes?

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, bson, mongodb-java

I have a lot of object with language code as a key field. Since both Java and Mongodb use UTF-8 natively and since the language codes are ASCII it seems to be that they should take 1 byte per character plus the \0 terminator. So the language code "en" should take only 3 bytes in the BSON object and in the index.

Is this correct? I am wondering whether I save anything by converting my fields to a byte array like:

```
byte[] lcBytes = langCode.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

before saving them to Mongodb with the Java driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [bson spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), it doesn't make a difference:

```
string  ::= int32 (byte*) "\x00"
binary  ::= int32 subtype (byte*)
```

In other words, the string is zero-terminated (hence wasting one byte), while the binary needs a one-byte subtype field.

Of course, a perfectly matching character set could be more efficient in that the byte array itself could be smaller (e.g. not require three bytes for a character you need very often, but only one). Then again, I hardly think it's worth the hassle, because it makes it impossible to use regex, map/reduce, js functions, etc. Maybe for very arcance charsets, but 8859-1 isn't too special.

As a sidenote, keep in mind that the [index size is limited to about 1k](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/), so you can't throw very long strings in the index (and it's not a good idea performance-wise).

If you only need to query by equality, maybe you could choose a hash instead? If you need to store very large strings (non-indexed), a compression algorithm might be a good idea.